# To convert string to logical format

Tags: r, paste

```
    xa <- c(TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE)
class(xa)
[1] "logical"
```

Here as we can see above is the sequence of TRUE and FALSE , when we try seeing the data type of XA object , it shows Logical type.

But when create a string of TRUE and FALSE and further I save in a object it shows data type as character , what required is data type should be logical.

```
      spliz <- paste("c(","TRUE,",paste(rep("FALSE",22),collapse=","),")")
   spliz <- gsub(" ","",spliz)
    class(spliz)
    [1] "character"
```

**so Required is above data type should come up to Logical**

Comment: You're pasting together strings that *happen* to have the same textual representation in R for boolean values. Are you looking for `eval(parse(text=spliz))`?

Comment: I need  create a Boolean sequence of TRUE and FALSE ,

Comment: putting the TRUE and FALSE values in quotes will result in them being read as strings. Could you not just use spliz <- c(TRUE, rep(FALSE, 22)) ?

Comment: Harvey, if not what ChrisLittler suggested, then what are you trying to do here? Programming by creating string-literals and expecting them to be instantly parsed into R code seems a little like [XKCD/378: Real Programmers](https://xkcd.com/378/). Perhaps it would help if you explain why you are trying to do this (as it doesn't seem like the preferred way to go in any of the languages I've used).

Comment: I agree with previous posters. There's probably a better way of approaching this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented, you should use `eval(parse(text=spliz))` which would give you logical values.

```
class(eval(parse(text=spliz))
[1] "logical"
```

Alternatively, you could just create the vector using `TRUE` and `FALSE` - or `T` and `F` instead of `"TRUE"` and `"FALSE"`.

Comment: In what is this answer different from @r2evans comment?

Comment: @RuiBarradas in that it's an answer and not a comment? :) r2evans could have answered it, but decided not to, probably because there's a better was of tackling the bedrock question.

Comment: No, they should not.